# Xcode 4.2 - Property IBOutlet won't Snap to Storyboard View

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4.2, storyboard

I'm learning about iPad development from the book Head First iPhone & iPad Development (2nd Edition).  I'm stuck in chapter 7, page 347.  This is the chapter on taking the DrinkMixer iPhone app and turning it into a universal app for both the iPhone and the iPad.

We added a split view controller (UISplitViewController) and the coding behind it all goes well (no build errors).  The one difference I'm doing is that I'm using storyboards.  Up to this point it's been going well, but now the book says to add a split view property IBOutlet (code below) for the detail view controller (*splitViewDetailView) and hook that @property up to the detail view.

MasterViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *drinks;
    DetailViewController *splitViewDetailView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *drinks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewController *splitViewDetailView;

@end
```

MasterViewController.m (top part)

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "AddDrinkViewController.h"
#import "DrinkConstants.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize drinks;
@synthesize splitViewDetailView;
```

The problem I'm having is that when I try to hook up the property to the detail view, it won't let me.  The connection wire won't snap into the view.  I've done many other IBOutlets and IBActions so far and it was easy to do.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried to search for a similar issues here on stack overflow and the web for the past 2 days and so far I've come up empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was going about this the wrong way. The solution was simpler than I thought.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898445/iboutlets-to-other-view-controllers-in-storyboard)

Thank you Marcus Buffett.  I'd vote you up but I don't have enough reputation points yet.