# UIPageViewController using Storyboard and Xcode 4.5

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller, xcode4.5

I want to ask some question about Xcode 4.5. I am creating app with storyboard. This app has `UIPageViewController`. But if I want to define identifier of `UIViewController` in IB of storyboard, there is no place for it anymore.

Can you please tell me, where can I simple define (using IB) identifier of view controller?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in XCode 4.5 Identifier below Attributes inspector has moved to Storyboard ID below Identy inspector.